# Proof of Lindenbaum lemma without deduction theorem

Tags: lo.logic

I'm working on a formalization of [Lindenbaum's completeness lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindenbaum%27s_lemma) for modal logic systems, but I've been stuck in a property. Namely, when trying to prove that:

$$\forall\Gamma,\forall\phi,\enspace\Gamma\ \textit{is consistent} \implies (\Gamma,\phi)\ \textit{is consistent}\ \lor\ (\Gamma,\neg\phi)\ \textit{is consistent}$$

Following some books, e.g., Blackburn's and Popkorn's, this seems to boil down to a lemma:

$$(\Gamma\vdash\phi)\iff (\Gamma,\neg\phi)\ \textit{is not consistent}$$

However, when trying to prove the only if side by contraposition, I get that, assuming:

1. $(\Gamma\vdash\phi)\implies\bot$
2. $\Gamma\ \textit{is consistent}$ (derivable from 1)
3. $\Gamma,\neg\phi \vdash \psi$
4. $\Gamma,\neg\phi \vdash \neg\psi$

...should derive a contradiction. I can see how to do that if I assume a deduction theorem, thus I can, from 3 and 4, derive both $\Gamma\vdash\neg\phi\rightarrow\psi$ and $\Gamma\vdash\neg\phi\rightarrow\neg\psi$, from which we derive that $\Gamma\vdash\phi$, which is a contradiction, as expected. However, I cannot see how to do this without the deduction theorem, which may not be available in the modal logic system. I'm not sure if I'm missing something, as I've seem this property even left as an exercise to the reader in a book (sorry, I forgot which one).

So, my questions: (1) can this be proved without using the deduction theorem? (2) If so, how? (3) If not so, does this mean that Lindenbaum's lemma actually depends on the deduction theorem?

Comment: Maybe have a look at Hakli and Negri's paper 'Does the deduction theorem fail for modal logic?', https://doi.org/10.1007/s11229-011-9905-9

Comment: Your property implies the deduction theorem: if $\Gamma,\phi\vdash\psi$, then $\Gamma,\neg(\phi\to\psi)$ is inconsistent, because $\neg(\phi\to\psi)\vdash\neg\psi$ and $\neg(\phi\to\psi)\vdash\phi$, whence $\Gamma,\neg(\phi\to\psi)\vdash\psi$ by the assumption.

Comment: Of course, the whole thing only makes good sense if $\vdash$ denotes the *local* consequence relation of the modal logic (where you can use theorems of the logic and modus ponens, but you cannot apply the necessitation rule to anything derived from nontautological premises).

Comment: Really, in the context of Lindenbaum’s lemma, consistency should be defined so that $\Gamma$ is consistent iff there is no finite subset $\Gamma_0\subseteq\Gamma$ such that $\vdash\neg\bigwedge\Gamma_0$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, I've been using a global consequence relation. In the version I'm using, there's no deduction theorem. Do you mean that Lindenbaum's lemma actually depends on it?

Comment: It does not make much sense to define inconsistency so that $\Gamma$ derives a contradiction using the *global* consequence relation. Lindenbaum's lemma simply does not hold in such a setting. It's not that it depends on the deduction theorem, but that you are using a wrong definition of consistency.

Comment: (Or rather, the version of Lindenbaum's lemma that you can prove for any finitary consequence relation is that any consistent set is included in a maximal consistent one. But with global consequence relation, "maximal consistent" will not imply "complete" in the sense that it has $\phi$ or $\neg\phi$ for any $\phi$.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, which notion of inconsistency should I be using for the global consequence relation? Do you have any reference on that? Every other piece of Lindenbaum's lemma seemed to work (and it's formalized: https://github.com/funcao/LML/blob/completeness/coq/Completeness.v). Can this be fixed?

Comment: The only way to make Lindenbaum's lemma work is to define consistency wrt the local consequence relation, irrespective of which consequence relation you are otherwise working with. Look, I don't know what is your aim, but the only application of Lindenbaum's lemma I have ever seen is to prove completeness of the logic. To prove completeness of modal logic wrt Kripke semantics, you need Lindenbaum's lemma for local consistency.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: yep, my goal so far was to prove completeness, but using the global consequence instead of the local one.

Comment: To prove Kripke completeness for the global consequence relation, you need Lindenbaum's lemma for consistency wrt the local consequence relation. I'm sorry, but that's just the way it works. Otherwise you'd prove completeness wrt one-element Kripke frames, which is absurd. Why don't you follow the completeness proof from some basic textbook.

Comment: Now that I've looked at your link, a few comments on your axioms: (1) ax10 is redundant. As is well known, already ax1–ax3 + mp completely axiomatize the implication–negation fragment of classical logic. (2) It appears both [] and <> are primitive operators in your setup. Then your axioms are incomplete: you need to replace axPos with the pair of defining implications  <>φ -> ~[]~φ, ~[]~φ -> <>φ. Otherwise you won't be able to prove any tautology that nontrivially combines [] and <>. (3) Warning: the logic GL is not canonical. You can't prove its completeness just using Lindenbaum's lemma.

Answer (score 3):

You need classical logic for this. Presumably the following rules for negation are valid in your logic:

1. Elimination rule: if $\Delta \vdash \psi$ and $\Delta \vdash \neg\psi$ then $\Delta \vdash \bot$.
2. Introduction rule: if $\Delta, \phi \vdash \bot$ then $\Delta \vdash \neg\phi$.
3. Classical logic: if $\Delta, \neg\phi \vdash \bot$ then $\Delta \vdash \phi$.

We say that $\Delta$ is *inconsistent* if $\Delta \vdash \bot$.

Let us prove that $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ if, and only if $\Gamma, \neg\phi \vdash \bot$:

- Assume $\Gamma \vdash \phi$. Then $\Gamma, \neg\phi \vdash \phi$ by weakening, and $\Gamma, \neg\phi \vdash \neg\phi$ by the hypothesis rule, therefore $\Gamma, \neg\phi \vdash \bot$ by the first rule above.
- Assume $\Gamma, \neg\phi \vdash \bot$. Then $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ by the third rule above.

If the above rules of negation are not valid in your logic, or if the definition of inconsistency is not the one I am using, then please specify the necessary information.

Comment: Indeed, if I have point 3 you mention this can be done. The system is indeed classic, as it has (as axioms) that $(\neg\phi\rightarrow\neg\psi)\rightarrow(\psi\rightarrow\phi)$ and that $\neg\neg\phi\rightarrow\phi$. Still, I'm not sure how to go from that into your point 3 without the deduction theorem. That's precisely where I'm stuck.

Comment: Is it a Hilbert-style system or natural deduction?

Comment: Hilbert style. I'm assuming the system has *at least* ten propositional axioms (including the two classical I mentioned above), plus K and possibility (modal). Those are listed in here: https://github.com/funcao/LML/blob/completeness/coq/Deductive_System.v#L24 (1 to 10, K, pos). It has modus poenens, but the deduction theorem is not derivable.